# How can I have the output from hot/cold water handles go to two different spigots?

Tags: plumbing

I am doing a renovation that will add a laundry sink to the basement and also allow an additional spigot on the exterior of the house. The new spigot will be in a convenient location for washing the car so I would like to be able to deliver warm water to this spigot.

Is there a way to hook up the laundry sink, so I can adjust the temperature at the sink and then flip a lever and the water to the faucet will turn off and go instead to the outdoor spigot? So, it would work a little bit like a bath where you can direct the water to the tub or to the shower.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure such a thing exists. But it would be quite inconvenient: Set water temperature, flip diverter, go outside, decide it is too hot/cold, run back inside to adjust. Ugh!

Instead, run both hot & cold to the outside, using [something like this](https://amzn.to/3rffuC8):

[image: hot and cold outdoor faucet]

Comment: I've used this one:  https://www.amazon.ca/Moen-HC400506-6-Inch-Faucets-Outdoor/dp/B0027Z2RLG